# Tkinter creates unexpected additional blank window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using Python 3.5 to create a simple GUI that takes in information from the user via a `textbox`, then saves to a `.txt` file.

What I've noticed is the following:

1. The `SaveButton` is automatically clicked at startup, but clicking again does nothing;
2. An additional, blank window, named tk, appears in the foreground.

This is my first GUI python application, so simplicity and patience are appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#Program by Fares Al Ghazy started 20/5/2017
#Python script to assign key combinations to bash commands, should run in the background at startup
#Since this program is meant to release bash code, it is obviously non-system agnostic and only works linux systems that use BASH
#Further versions which support more OSs may come to life
#This is one file which only creates the GUI, another file is needed to use the info taken by this program

import tkinter as tk
#function to write to file
def SaveFunction(e1,e2):
    print("opening file")
    file = open("BinderData.txt","a")
    combo = e1.get()
    print("combo =" + combo)
    performed = e2.get()
    print("action = " + performed)
    print("Writing to file")
    file.write(combo)
    file.write(performed)
    print("closing file")
    file.close()
    print("file closed")

class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        #create GUI to take in key combinations and bash codes, then save them in file
        root = tk.Tk() # create new window
        root.wm_title("Key binder") #set title
        #create labels and text boxes
        KeyComboLabel = tk.Label(root,text = "Key combination = ")
        KeyComboEntry = tk.Entry(root)

        ActionLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "Command to be executed = ")
        ActionEntry = tk.Entry(root)
        #place widgets in positions
        KeyComboLabel.grid(row=0,column =0,sticky = tk.E)
        ActionLabel.grid(row=1,column =0, sticky = tk.E)

        KeyComboEntry.grid(row=0,column =1)
        ActionEntry.grid(row=1,column =1)
        #create save button
        SaveButton= tk.Button(root,text = "save")
        SaveButton.grid(row=2,column =2, sticky = tk.E , command = SaveFunction(KeyComboEntry,ActionEntry))

app = MainFrame()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You execute the `SaveFunction` callback and bind the *result* to the `command` parameter; try a `lambda` expression instead. Also, the `command` parameter has to go to the constructor, not to the layout function.

   ```
   SaveButton= tk.Button(root,text = "save", command = lambda: SaveFunction(KeyComboEntry,ActionEntry))
   SaveButton.grid(row=2,column =2, sticky = tk.E )
   ```
2. You get the additional empty window because you create two `Tk` instances, the first being the `MainFrame` itself, extending `Tk`, and the second the `Tk()` you create in `__init__`. Instead of creating another `Tk`, just use `self` as `root`:

   ```
   root = self # or change all "root" to "self" in the code below
   ```

   Or don't have `MainFrame` extend `Tk`.

---

Some more clarification about the `command` callback part and `lambda`. The problem, as I said, is that you execute the function and then bind the result of that execution to `command`. To make this clearer, `command=SaveFunction(KeyComboEntry, ActionEntry)` is the same as

```
cmd = SaveFunction(KeyComboEntry, ActionEntry)
SaveButton= tk.Button(root, text="save", command=cmd)
```

which is obviously not what you want. If you would call a function with no parameters, you could just use `command=SaveFunction` without `()`, thus not calling the function but using the function *itself* as a parameter, but since `SaveFunction` needs parameters, you have to define an in-line `lambda`, calling `SaveFunction`, which itself takes no parameters.

Comment: Worked perfectly and good explanation, so thank you.
Could you please elaborate more on the lambda part though?

Comment: @FaresAlGhazy What exactly do you need to know? `command` expects a function, and `lambda` is a way to define a function in-line.

Comment: Thanks again, I guess I'm just confused as to why it needs to be defined in-line when I already defined, declared, and implemented it at the top of my application?